# BufferedWriter not printing

Tags: java

I am trying to organise usernames and passwords into slots and assuming the username is not an email, I treat it as a password. I have to put these into files however it is not printing. It is reading though. Could I get some help? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Core {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileReader in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    BufferedWriter uOut = null;
    BufferedWriter pOut = null;

    try {

        in = new FileReader("src/input.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(in);

        uOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/username.txt"));

        pOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/password.txt"));

        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {

            boolean migrated = true;

            if(line.contains(":")) {

                String[] split = line.split(":");
                String user = split[0];
                String pass = split[1];

                if(!(user.contains("@") && user.contains(".com"))) {
                    migrated = false;
                }

                if(migrated) {
                    uOut.write(user, 0, user.length());
                    uOut.newLine();

                    pOut.write(pass, 0, pass.length());
                    pOut.newLine();
                } else {
                    pOut.write(user, 0, user.length());
                    pOut.newLine();
                    pOut.write(pass, 0, pass.length());
                    pOut.newLine();
                }

                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }

            if(!(line.contains("@") && line.contains(".com"))) {
                pOut.write(line, 0, line.length());
                pOut.newLine();

                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            } else {
                uOut.write(line, 0, line.length());
                uOut.newLine();

                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }

        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }

        if(uOut != null) try { uOut.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }

        if(pOut != null) try { pOut.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }

    }

}
```

}

I should also mention that I do not get any exceptions and have no errors to show.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: unless this is a "learning" project: you **never ever** print passwords into files. You only keep hashed, salted versions of your passwords around; and you never ever (like in never ever) store passwords as directly, as text.

Comment: Yeah I'm mostly trying to learn for now.

Comment: Is it possible that a smarter solution might be to arrange the user/pass into array lists and then iterate over them and put them into their respective files? Or would it be the same outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with a file `data.txt`

```
foo:bar
blarg:bletch
blahonga:baar
```

Code with small changes

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileReader in = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        BufferedWriter uOut = null;
        BufferedWriter pOut = null;

        try {

            in = new FileReader("data.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(in);

            uOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("username.txt"));

            pOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("password.txt"));

            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                boolean migrated = true;

                if (line.contains(":")) {

                    String[] split = line.split(":");
                    String user = split[0];
                    String pass = split[1];
                    if (user.contains("@") && user.contains(".com")) {
                        migrated = false;
                    }

                    if (migrated) {
                        uOut.write(user, 0, user.length());
                        uOut.newLine();

                        pOut.write(pass, 0, pass.length());
                        pOut.newLine();
                    } else {
                        pOut.write(user, 0, user.length());
                        pOut.newLine();
                        pOut.write(pass, 0, pass.length());
                        pOut.newLine();
                    }

                    line = br.readLine();
                    continue;
                }

                if (!(line.contains("@") && line.contains(".com"))) {
                    pOut.write(line, 0, line.length());
                    pOut.newLine();

                    line = br.readLine();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    uOut.write(line, 0, line.length());
                    uOut.newLine();

                    line = br.readLine();
                    continue;
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (br != null) try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

            if (uOut != null) try {
                uOut.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

            if (pOut != null) try {
                pOut.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The result is 2 files:

**username.txt**

```
foo
blarg
blahonga
```

**password.txt**

```
bar
bletch
baar
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me where you put the files because for some reason, wherever I put them, I get a "FileNotFoundException"

Comment: @MrGbtank You might want to supply an absolute path for example `in = new FileReader("/home/alice/data.txt");` or similar. I use IntelliJ IDEA and choose the execution directory from inside IntelliJ.

Comment: Right. Well thanks, for the help. I ran your code and it seemed to work. I think I found my issue and it was something to do with the files. I don't really understand it but it seems to work now. Thanks, again.